# AppbarLayout and NestedScrollView Overlaps while opening the Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, nestedscrollview

Nested ScrollView has fragments which have `RecyclerView` and `AppbarLayout` does not scroll when dragged.
I have even added `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in my `RecyclerView` as suggested in some answer but that does not work.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_view_cl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_control_highlight"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_8dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.practo.docnet.widgets.FlingBehavior"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/color_primary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/color_white"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5">


                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/profile_pic_margin_bottom"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_pic_margin_top"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/card_padding"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/default_elevation"
                        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/profile_pic_iv"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_pic_size"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_pic_size"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/profile_pic_margin"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"

                            />
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/cover_pic"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/cover_pic_height"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/profile_placeholder"
                            android:tint="@color/cover_pic_tint" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/layout_titles"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/titles_layout_height"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/titles_layout_margin_top"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/first_name_tv"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                android:gravity="bottom|center"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_sz_xxxlarge" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/designation_tv"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/designation_text_margin_top"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_sz_xlarge" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/location_tv"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/location_text_margin_top"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_sz_xlarge" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/no_of_connections_tv"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_padding_more"
                                android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_primary"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_sz_xxlarge" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/connections_text_tv"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/connections_text_margin_top"
                                android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:text="@string/connections"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_sz_xlarge" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </FrameLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/back_icon"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title_textview"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_sz_xxlarge" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foregroundGravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cards_layout_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/profile_connect_layout" />
```

Comment: The thing is, where is the `RecyclerView` in your codes? you should add it too.and please update the codes with the entire codes(even with closed tags!).